# Sorting php array by value

Tags: php

I have this array in my php code:

```
    Array
(
    [190] => 2
    [193] => 1
    [196] => 1
    [199] => 1
    [206] => 2
    [208] => 2

)
```

I need to sort it in descending order. I am doing this:

```
$sortDid = arsort($dids);
```

But this is not working. What's wrong here?

Comment: how  *But this is not working* ?

Comment: Have you tried rsort?

Answer (score 5):

`arsort` modify array by reference. `arsort` returns `bool` value. Remove assign to variable:

```
arsort($dids);
var_dump($dids);
```